# Validation jquery issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, jquery-validate

I really need help here, I'm Working on a validation form, the validation is working. My question is how can I present the errors specific to the field and next to the field?
Right now if  the user typed invalid phone and invalid mail , It shows "phone must be 9-10 digits", in both fields(email and phone) . so what I want is to show the error that realted to the field in every field.

```js
$('.xone-contact').submit(function() {
  var $form = $(this);
  var $form1 = $(this);
  var $form2 = $(this);
  var submitData = $form.serialize();
  var $phone = $form1.find('input[name="phone"]');
  var $email = $form2.find('input[name="email"]');
  var $name = $form.find('input[name="name"]');
  var $message = $form.find('textarea[name="message"]');
  var $submit = $form.find('input[name="submit"]');
  var $dataStatus = $form.find('.data-status');
  var $dataStatus1 = $form1.find('.phone_error');
  var $dataStatus2 = $form2.find('.email_error');

  $email.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  $phone.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  $name.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  $message.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  $submit.attr('disabled', 'disabled');

  $dataStatus.show().html('<div class="alert alert-info"><strong>Loading...</strong></div>');

  $.ajax({ // Send an offer process with AJAX
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'assets/contact_form/process-contact.php',
    data: submitData + '&action=add',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(msg) {
      if (parseInt(msg, 0) !== 0) {
        var msg_split = msg.split('|');
        if (msg_split[0] === 'success') {
          $phone.val('').removeAttr('disabled');
          $email.val('').removeAttr('disabled');
          $name.val('').removeAttr('disabled');
          $message.val('').removeAttr('disabled');
          $submit.removeAttr('disabled');
          $dataStatus.html(msg_split[1]).fadeIn();
        } else {
          $phone.removeAttr('disabled');
          $email.removeAttr('disabled');
          $name.removeAttr('disabled');
          $message.removeAttr('disabled');
          $submit.removeAttr('disabled');
          $dataStatus.html(msg_split[1]).fadeIn();
          $dataStatus1.html(msg_split[1]).fadeIn();
          $dataStatus2.html(msg_split[1]).fadeIn();
        }
      }
    }
  });

  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="#" class="xone-contact">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class=" margin-b-20">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Full Name...." />
      </div>
      <div class=" margin-b-20">
        <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email Address...." />
        <div class="email_error">
        </div>
        <div class=" margin-b-20">
          <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Phone Number..." />
          <div class="phone_error">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <textarea name="message" class="form-control margin-b-20" rows="5" id="massage" placeholder="Message...."></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
          <div class="data-status"></div>
          <!-- data submit status -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
          <button type="submit" name="submit" id="contact_submit button" class="btn btn-lg btn-skin-border btn-block margin-b-20">Send Message</button>
        </div>
      </div>
</form>
<!--form end-->
```

Comment: You can use some validation library, here is one https://github.com/isneezy/confere.js if you are using npm can use `npm install confere.js --save`

Comment: Instead of reinventing the wheel, there are plenty of validation plugins out there. jQuery validation is one of them: https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 form inputs have ability to check the pattern by itself, so there is no need to send them to server to validate it - you could use something like this:

```
<input type=text pattern="[0-9]{9,10}" title="Enter 10 digits phone number" placeholder="phone">
```

`title` property is used as an error message in case of incorrect input.

[Documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-pattern)

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f298v432/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library [Confere.js](https://github.com/isneezy/confere.js) to achieve your goal!
It is in heavy development now but I think it feet your needs. 
For the phone validation i think you can use the `min` and `max` rules or you can implement your own by using:

```
Confere.validaor("phone", function(name, value, params, options){
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      if(success){ resolve() } //when pass
      else{
         var error = new Error('Error Message');
         error.field = name;
         reject(error);
      }
   });
});
```

Exemple:

```js
$('.x-contact-form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var confere = new Confere({
    rules: this
  })

  confere.validate().then(function() {
  
    //submit your form
    
  }).catch(function(err) {
  
  //remove all errors notifications
    Object.keys(confere.options.rules).map(function(key){
      $(`.${key}-group`).removeClass('has-error');
      $(`.${key}-group`).addClass('has-success');
      $(`#${key}_error`).text('');
    });
    
    //add errors on fields that failed validation
    Object.keys(err.result).map(function(key) {
      $(`.${key}-group`).addClass('has-error');
      $(`#${key}_error`).text(err.result[key][0].message);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/isneezy/confere.js/master/lib/confere.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form class="x-contact-form" style="max-width: 300px; margin: 10px">
  <div class="form-group name-group">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="name" data-rule="required|min:3|max:254" />
    <span id="name_error" class="text-danger"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group email-group">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="email" data-rule="required|email|max:254" />
    <span id="email_error" class="text-danger"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group phone-group">
    <label>Phone</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="phone" data-rule="required|max:9" />
    <span id="phone_error" class="text-danger"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group message-group">
    <label>Message</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="message" data-rule="required|min:20|max:254"></textarea>
    <span id="message_error" class="text-danger"></span>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send" />
</form>
```